# Convert messages to arrays using jq

Tags: arrays, json, bash, shell, jq

My messages generator output

```bash
$ ./messages.sh
{"a":"v1"}
{"b":"v2"}
{"c":"v3"}
...
```

Required output

```bash
$ ./messages.sh | jq xxxxxx
[{"a":"v1"},{"b":"v2"}]
[{"c":"v3"},{"d":"v4"}]
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the first item using `.`, and the second using `input` (prepended by `try` to handle cases of not enough input items). Then, wrap them both into array brackets, and provide the `-c` option for compact output. jq will work through its whole input one by one (or two by two).

```bash
./messages.sh | jq -c '[., try input]'
```

```json
[{"a":"v1"},{"b":"v2"}]
[{"c":"v3"},{"d":"v4"}]
```

---

> What if I want more objects in the array than 2? For example, 3, 10, 100?

You can surround the array body with `limit`, and use `inputs` instead (note the `s`) to fetch more than just one item:

```bash
./messages.sh | jq -c '[limit(3; ., try inputs)]'
```

```json
[{"a":"v1"},{"b":"v2"},{"c":"v3"}]
[{"d":"v4"}]
```

Comment: Yes, this solution has three advantages over the slurp/_nwise one: space efficiency, time efficiency (because the current implementation of _nwise  in jq is careless), and portability (e.g to gojq).

Comment: However, if there is an odd number of input entities, this will ignore the last, and produce an error message. One workaround: jq -c '[., input? // empty]'

Comment: Thank you. One more question. What if I want more objects in the array than 2? For example, 3, 10, 100?

Comment: @kolisko I have added `try` to meet the "odd" case, and an extended version using `limit` to handle more items at once.

Comment: @pmf it is even better, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `slurp` with `_nwise(2)` to chunk into parts of 2:

```
jq --slurp --compact-output '_nwise(2)' <<< $(./messages.sh)
```

```json
[{"a":"v1"},{"b":"v2"}]
[{"c":"v3"},{"d":"v4"}]
```

---

The `--compact-output` is to output each array on a single line

Comment: thank you for solution but this is very slow under heavy load

Answer (score 1):

Here is a stream-oriented, generic and portable def of nwise:

```
# Group the items in the given stream into arrays of up to length $n
# assuming $n is a non-negative integer > 0
# Input: a stream
# Output: a stream of arrays no longer than $n
# such that [stream] == ([ nwise(stream; $n) ] | add)
# Notice that there is no assumption about an eos marker.
def nwise(stream; $n):
  foreach ((stream | [.]), null) as $x ([];
    if $x == null then . 
    elif length == $n then $x
    else . + $x end;
    if $x == null and length>0 then .
    elif length==$n then .
    else empty
    end);
```

For the task at hand, you could use it like so:

```
nwise(inputs; 2)
```

with the -n command-line option.